# &deg; not showing in placeholder when added with .placeholder

Tags: javascript, input, placeholder

I'm trying to use .placeholder to change the placeholder text on an input. I'm using

```
&deg;
```

to get a °

```
cel.onclick = function() {
    cel.className += "active";
    reset();
    faren.classList.remove("active");
    inp.placeholder = "Enter &deg;C";
};

faren.onclick = function() {
    faren.className += "active";
    reset();
    cel.classList.remove("active");
    inp.placeholder = "Enter &deg;F";
};
```

This outputs `&deg;` instead of the symbol, can anyone explain how to change this. Thanks.

Comment: Is there anything stopping you from just pasting the actual ° symbol into your placeholder string?

Comment: you mean it outputs &deg;?

Comment: Yes, sorry forgot to add it as code

Comment: inp.placeholder = 'Enter '+String.fromCharCode(176)+ 'C';

Comment: Actually there isn't @Zac I feel a bit stupid as I've just had to google how to put the ° symbol. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you @Gurkan Yesilyurt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the javascript character escape code (like `\u00B0`) for the symbol instead of the HTML entity code (like `&deg;`):

```
inp.placeholder = "Enter \u00B0C";
```

You can use  [this web tool](https://r12a.github.io/app-conversion/) to do find the javascript character escape given an HTML entity.